# Show two spaces are isomorpic

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm supposed to show, that two spaces are isomorph. The first is dual to $X$, where
$$X=(l^1,\|\cdot\|),\ \|x\|=\|x\|_1+\|x\|_\infty$$
the second is
$$Y=(l^\infty,\|\cdot\|),\ \|(x_n)\|_a=\sup\left\{\frac{1}{|M|+1}\sum_{n\in M}|x_n|;\ M\subset\mathbb{N}\text{ finite}\right\}$$
The norm on the $X^*$ space should be:
$$\|x^*\|_b=\|(x_n)\|_b=\sup\left\{\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}|x_n a_n|;\ \max{a_n}+\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n\leq1\right\}$$
So now it remains to prove that $\exists c,d>0:\ c\|(x_n)\|_a\leq\|(x_n)\|_b\leq d\|(x_n)\|_a$

I haven't made any progress on this so far.

Comment: I figured this out: $\|(x_n)\|_b\geq\|(x_n)\|_a$, because we can always choose $a_n=\frac{1}{|M|+1}$ for the corresponding $n$s and the set the rest 0, which means that $c=1$

Comment: You should include your progress in the question, rather than in a comment.